# Running Scripts during appx installation

Tags: installation, windows-store-apps, appx

Is it possible to run the pre-installation scripts or the post-installation scripts during appx installation time? If it is possible how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. The only way to achieve something like this is to create something like a MSI wrapper around your AppX package and from the MSI run custom scripts before and after you install the AppX package (using another script, PowerShell for example).

I would not recommend such a solution, but in theory it is possible.